# Download images from amazon s3 bucket in Node js in zip format

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, zip

I am using Node js and amazon s3 service to store the images. I have different folders in bucket.each folder have sub folders. Can anyone suggest a way to download particular files in their original size combined as zip files.
It will be helpful if i can specify image keys or urls and those will be downloaded.

Answer (score 1):

s3 does not allow you to zip a file and download, it however allows you to compress files before upload which can be downloaded separately.

This means your download will always be the full or part of the file you uploaded and not the other way around.

You can always download multiple files using the [listObjects](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#listObjects-property) command with **prefix** of files you need to download, followed by [getObject](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#listObjects-property) on each of the listed objects

Answer (score 1):

One way is you can get all the images by using [AWS-SDK](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js) package's getObject() method by specifying the key and bucket information.

You can use [JSZip](https://stuk.github.io/jszip/) to zip the images. After that you can either save the zip to amazon s3 and provide URL to user or use 'fs' package to save to local computer.

I am placing here sample code i used

```
  s3 = new AWS.S3({
        endpoint: s3url
    }),
    zip = new JSZip();
 function() {
        var albumImages = [{"name":filename,"key":key}], // contains image key and filename
            content = null; 
               // using async eachLimit to get images parallely 

        async.eachLimit(albumImages, 10, function(albumImage, next) { 
            var params = {
                Bucket: imageBucket, // bucket name
                Key: albumImage.key
            };
            s3.getObject(params, function(err, data) {
                if (err) {
                    console.log('get image files err',err, err.stack); // an error occurred

                } else {
                    zip.file(albumImages.indexOf(albumImage) + albumImage.name, data.Body);
                    next();
                }
            });
        }, function(err) {
            if (err) {
                console.log('err', err);

            } else {
                content = zip.generate({
                    type: 'nodebuffer'
                });
                var params = {
                    Bucket: archiveBucket, // name of dest bucket
                    Key: 'images.zip',
                    Body: content
                };
                s3.putObject(params, function(err, data) {
                    if (err) {
                        console.log('upload zip to s3 err',err, err.stack); // an error occurred

                    } else {
                        console.log(data); // successful response

                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }
```

Here i am saving zip again into another s3 bucket.
You can also use the aws lambda to do this zip.

Comment: I have created something very similar to your code, but ready for use as a service. It might be useful for the OP as another example; https://github.com/gammasoft/zipper